# Qt5 linux how to set window icon image

Tags: linux, cmake, icons, qt5, qmainwindow

I have a UI I have designed in Qt designer and have written the code in c++. I am using [catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin), which is just cmake, to build my project. Currently when the program is launched, the application icon looks like,[image]
.I would like to have that be an image that I specify, but have been unable to figure out how to get this to work.

My project directory structure looks like the following

```
package
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--src
    |--main.cpp 
    |--MainWindow.cpp
    |--resources
       |--images
           |--kitty.png
       |--icons.qrc
|--include
    |--MainWindow.hpp
|--ui
    |--MainWindow.ui
```

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
project(shared_memory_transport_sliderboard)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}     ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

set(INCLUDES_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(SOURCES_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS ${INCLUDES_DIR}
DEPENDS Qt5Widgets
)

# c++11
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no     C++0x support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

include_directories(
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
${INCLUDES_DIR}
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(QT_FORMS
ui/MainWindow.ui
)
set(QT_MOC 
    ${INCLUDES_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/MainWindow.h
)
set(QT_SOURCES
    src/MainWindow.cpp
)

qt5_wrap_cpp(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})
qt5_wrap_ui(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
qt5_add_resources(ui_resources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/icons.qrc)

add_executable(smt_sliderboard src/main.cpp ${QT_SOURCES}   ${QT_MOC_HPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${ui_resources})

target_link_libraries(smt_sliderboard ${catkin_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets)

install(TARGETS smt_sliderboard
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

When compiling my code the compiler does generate a `qrc_icons.cpp.o` object, but when I run the executable the icon doesn't show up. The icons.qrc file I have looks like,

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="/Icons">
        <file alias="kitty">images/kitty.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I have also tried adding the following in MainWindow.h,

```
QApplication myApp(argc, argv);
QIcon appIcon;
appIcon.addFile(":/Icons/kitty");
myApp.setWindowIcon(appIcon);
```

and this compiles just fine, but still no icon. Feel like I have tried everything with no luck, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc) docs:

> Note that the listed resource files must be located in the same
>   directory as the .qrc file, or one of its subdirectories.

So you need a directory structure something like:

```
|--images
    |--images
       |--kitty.png
    |--icons.qrc
```

**UPDATE**:

You should also consult [Setting the Application Icon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html) in the Qt docs to make sure you deal with any platform-specific issues.

Comment: Nice catch! I updated my directory structure accordingly and still no dice though..

Comment: Surely that should be: `appIcon.addFile(":/images/kitty.png");`?

Comment: I think I have it correct right? Check out the stuff [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc) about the ```prefix``` and ```alias```

Comment: Well, yes, I know how it works - but I can't see what's in your qrc file. and your original question didn't appear to use an alias. Have you actually checked to see if you can read the resource using `QFile`?

Comment: Oops sorry, I added the contents of the .qrc file to the question. Also I created a ```QFile``` like ```QFile test(":/Icons/kitty")``` and it  compiled and ran just fine.

Comment: @jlack. Just to be clear: did you actually open and **read** the resource? Or as a simpler test, can you create a pixmap and display it in a `QLabel`? And another thing which is not completely clear is what you mean by "application icon". Are you talking about icons in the title-bar, or on the desktop? Because if it's the latter, it's a platform-specific thing (see my updated answer).

Comment: I don't really know how to display a pixmap in a ```QLabel```. I'm kind of a Qt noob. And I don't mean a desktop icon. I really just mean the title bar icon. Like for example(on Ubuntu Unity) when you hit Alt+tab and you can scroll through the list of opened applications.

Comment: @jlack. `label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/Icons/kitty"));`.

Comment: @jlack. So it's a plaform-specific issue with ubuntu unity. See the link in my answer - you probably need to create a .desktop file.

Comment: I got it working. Not actually 100% sure what made it work. I switched my window manager to Gnome-Shell, but I don't think right when I switched it the Icon showed up. I also changed ```QIcon appIcon;
appIcon.addFile(":/Icons/kitty");
myApp.setWindowIcon(appIcon);``` to ```QIcon appIcon(":/Icons/kitty")
myApp.setWindowIcon(appIcon);```